# Generate matrix np python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I need to write a function that generate the below matrix.

[image]

I wrote this code:

```
def second_composition(n, m):
    upper_triangle = np.triu_indices(n, 1)
    ones = np.ones((n, m))
    ones[upper_triangle] = -1

    return ones


n = 6
m = 6

result_second_composition = second_composition(n, m)

print(result_second_composition)
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: What is the output of your code, and what is wrong with your output?

Comment: @Jeff I added the output at the question.

Comment: Please post text, not images. See [ask]

Comment: Your instructions show a square matrix but you are processing non-square matrices. What gives with the two inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `np.cumsum` along `axis=0` -

```
def second_composition(n, m):
    upper_triangle = np.triu_indices(n, 1)
    ones = np.cumsum(np.ones((n, m)), axis=0) #<----
    ones[upper_triangle] = -1

    return ones

second_composition(5,5)
```

```
array([[ 1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [ 2.,  2., -1., -1., -1.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3., -1., -1.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4., -1.],
       [ 5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.]])
```

---

Another way you could do this is by using `triu(k=1)` + `tril()`. The k=1 is the diagonal for upper matrix.

```
def compose(n,m):
    ones = np.ones((n,m))
    out = np.tril(np.cumsum(ones,0)) + -1*np.triu(ones,k=1)
    return out

compose(6,6)
```

```
array([[ 1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [ 2.,  2., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3., -1., -1., -1.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4., -1., -1.],
       [ 5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5., -1.],
       [ 6.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  6.]])
```

Comment: Added another slightly neater method. Do mark the answer as correct if it solved your question. Thanks!

Comment: I added a method that is arguably neater still :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what `tril_indices` returns for the row index: it's basically what you want in the lower half of the matrix:

```
def second_composition(n):
    m = np.ones((n, n))
    r, c = np.tril_indices(n)
    m[r, c] = r + 1
    return m
```

Answer (score -2):

Assuming it has to be a square matrix where m == n, add the following to your definition

```
lower_triangle = np.tril_indices(m,)
    ones[upper_triangle] = -1
    for i, j in zip(lower_triangle[0], lower_triangle[1]):
        ones[i][j] = i+1
```